# Windows 8.1 sharing Internet connection via network bridge to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have an Ubuntu desktop that I want connected to the Internet; the built-in WLAN adapter is broken, so I'd like to connect it to my main Windows desktop that *does* have a working WLAN adapter via an Ethernet cable to share the Internet connection.

I read that the easiest way to share Internet using an Ethernet cable is to bridge the Ethernet adapter and WLAN adapter on the main computer, and that was done easily enough on Windows. However, the Ubuntu desktop can't connect to the Internet after connecting it to the Windows desktop. Windows shows the Ethernet adapter as being 'not connected', but is sending (but not recieving) packets. Ubuntu seems to recognise the Ethernet cable as being plugged in, but it won't get past showing 'Requesting an ethernet network address for 'Wired Connection 1'...".

What should I do to make this work?

Windows ipconfig results

[image: Windows ipconfig results]

Ubuntu ifconfig results

[image: Ubuntu ifconfig results]

Windows Network Connections

[image: Windows Network Connections]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this afternoon; in Ubuntu, I went to Network Connections, edited the Wired connection, went to IPV4, and manually set the IP address to 192.168.0.46 and the gateway to 192.168.0.1 (the same gateway that shows up on the Windows computer's Ethernet adapter under "Details"). After restarting the Ubuntu machine, I had Internet access, and using the Android app "Network Scanner" by First Row, the Ubuntu machine shows up as connected to the WLAN network despite only being connected via Ethernet cable to the Windows machine.